# Prevent Elements in Navbar from going to a second row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with the alignment in the following `navbar` that uses Bootstrap 3.

**Problem:** The `Login` and `Signup` elements are on different rows. Whats the correct way to adjust them so that they are both on the same line? `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;` does not appear to work on the `li` elements.

Note that the `input` element should fill up the space between the logo and the Login/Signup elements.

**Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/Bh5TBV9vS0

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

**HTML**

```
    <a class="brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png" width="100">
    </a>

    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal search-form">        
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-search"></i> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </form>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/users/sign_in">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.brand {
    width: 170px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block
}

.navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.search-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-form {
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav { display: flex; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float:left` for your list items and apply `dispaly:inline-block` and apply the style `white-space:nowrap` for your `ul` element.

```
  ul.navbar-nav{ white-space:nowrap;}
 .navbar-nav li{display:inline-block; float:none;}
```

Comment: Would you know another method for Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated width of `.search-form` from `100% to 76%` and now it works fine.

Check [here](http://www.bootply.com/ZWzOf77CID)